# repeat a value in a matrix for a matching ID (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, matrix

I need your help in solving the following problem.  Column1 shows a grouping by integer.  Any non-nan value in Col2 should be inserted in the matrix for matching groupnumber(Col1).

```
mat = [ ...
        1  nan 
        1  0.1
        1  nan
        1  nan
        2  nan
        2  nan
        2  nan
        3  0.5
        4  nan
        4  nan
        4  nan
        5  0.2
        5  nan ] ;

ans = [ ...
        1  0.1 
        1  0.1
        1  0.1
        1  0.1
        2  nan
        2  nan
        2  nan
        3  0.5
        4  nan
        4  nan
        4  nan
        5  0.2
        5  0.2 ] ;
```

Please recommend a vectorized approach.  Data is huge and is already being run in a for-loop.  There will never be multiple non-nan values(col2) within a group (in mat).  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution using [ACCUMARRAY](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/accumarray.html) will accomplish your goal:

```
values = accumarray(mat(:,1),mat(:,2),[],@min);
mat(:,2) = values(mat(:,1));
```

I use the function [MIN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/min.html) here for convenience, since it will return the non-`NaN` value if there is one, or `NaN` if that's all there is. It's simpler than the logic involved in checking for any non-`NaN` values using, say, the function [ISNAN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/isnan.html). You could actually use the function [MAX](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/max.html) as well, since it behaves the same way in this case.

Comment: Thanks Gnovice! I really need to get comfortable with accumarray!

Comment: @Maddy: the description is not complete: if you had multiple non-nan values in the same group (different values), do you want to use the `min` to replace the nan's in the same group?

Comment: @Amro - thanks for pointing that out. I have edited the Q.  There cannot be multiple non-nan values within a group.  In real life, those values are month-end exchange rates. Groups are made from middle of last month to (middle-1) day of next month.  Should I remove `@min` from Gnovice's code?  I am not very aware of accumarray powers.

Comment: @Maddy: I added an extra explanation for why I used `@min`.

Comment: @gnovice...I have implemented it and the results are good and fast!